# Include guards in c++ for main method

Tags: c++

I know the purpose and usage of include guards around the .h file in C++

```
  #ifndef FILENAME_H
  #define FILENAME_H
  #endif
```

However, I am trying to understand the usage for #ifdef TEST_FILENAME in the test stub or around the main() method used to test run the class.

```
  #ifdef TEST_FILENAME
   void main()
   {
      /////////////////
   }
  #endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably so that you can have a conditional main function run.

If you're testing, you'll want a test routine to run, if not you'll probably want to execute your actual main function. This allows you define the macro during compile-time so that the preprocessor can give you the right main to build.

Answer (score 1):

A program can only have one main() entry point.

Therefore, if this test code is in a file which will be compiled and linked into your release executable, it needs to be conditionalized so that it's only compiled in a special test build, otherwise your build will fail with a link error due to main() being multiply defined.

Generally speaking, this is a poor way to structure testing code - tests should be in properly structured unit tests which are separate from your production code.